# calling julia by using exec in php

Tags: php, matlab, julia

Thank u for your reading. Uh, I am using php function exec to call julia to run a script in windows. My server version is apache2.2 and php version is php6.0.0. I failed to call julia to run the xxx.jl script by using exec function in php. I have tried many ways to find the cause of the problem:

1. I ran the php script to call matlab to run the "test.m" file to find if I have the authority to run "exec" function in my computer, then I succeeded.
2. I ran the test.jl script from DOS. It succeeded. But when I use the function "exec" in php it didn't work any more. I don't think it's because I didn't configure the php.ini correctly since I did step 1 smoothly.

Can someone tell me what should I do to call julia to run a jl script from php through DOS. Other better methods to call julia or julia studio to run a jl script will be okay, too. Thank u very much!
By the way I used the julia REPL to do the test. I haven't find any way to call julia studio to run a script without opening the software as I do in matlab. Is there any way to do so through julia studio?

Comment: What is the error? Assuming you use a webserver (which one? which setup?), does it work if you invoke the PHP script from the commandline instead of the webserver? What do the logs say? Did you enable error-reporting in the PHP configuration?

Comment: Thank you for your response very much. I didn't realize I can invoke the PHP script from the commandline. Yes, I tried to invoke it form the commandline. It works but it still doesn't work when I invoke it from the webserver.  I install AppServ (which download from http://www.appservnetwork.com/ )in my computer. The info of the software in the package is :Apache 2.2.8，PHP 6.0.0-dev，MySQL 6.0.4-alpha，phpMyAdmin-2.10.3.

Comment: I just check the error.log of apache. There is no new errors information in the file. So it may not be an error. I also check the access.log but I still cannot find any difference between calling julia and calling matlab from the information in this file.